# Logical Replication for Aurora Postgres in Java

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

My goal is to stream the Postgres WAL inside a system that runs on the JVM. I am using Aurora RDS Postgres.

If I try to run the following:

```
    PGReplicationStream stream =
        pgConnection.getReplicationAPI()
            .replicationStream()
            .logical()
            .withSlotName("test_slot")
            .withStartPosition(lsn)
            .start();
```

I get the error:

```
; (err) ERROR: syntax error at or near "START_REPLICATION"
; (err)   Position: 1
```

Postgres logs the following command:

```
:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "START_REPLICATION" at character 1
:STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT test_slot LOGICAL 0/40DCC70;
```

This does look like the command the jdbc driver is trying to write. (as seen [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/f61fbfe7b72ccf2ca0ac2e2c366230fdb93260e5/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/replication/V3ReplicationProtocol.java#L91-L96))

START_REPLICATION does seem to be a command Postgres supports. Is it that Aurora RDS does not support this? If so, is there an alternative way to do this?

---

For completeness, here's the code I've built up so far. I am using Clojure, but most of this is calling directly into java functions.

```
  ; pool is HikariCP
  (def pg-conn (-> pool
                   (.getConnection)
                   (.unwrap org.postgresql.PGConnection)))

  ;; create slot
  (sql/execute! pool ["SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('instant_server_stopa', 'wal2json');"])

  ;; log sequence number
  (def lsn (org.postgresql.replication.LogSequenceNumber/valueOf
            (:pg_current_wal_lsn (sql/select-one pg-conn
                                                 ["SELECT pg_current_wal_lsn()"]))))
  (def s (-> pg-conn
             (.getReplicationAPI)
             (.replicationStream)
             (.logical)
             (.withSlotName "instant_server_stopa")
             (.withStartPosition lsn)
             (.start)))
```

Comment: Could you post complete code, or link to a complete example?

Comment: I updated the question with more complete code, thanks @jjanes

Comment: I don't know how to test something in Clojure, but I think you are correct, you need to declare the intention for your connection to be a replication connection at the time the connection is first created.  It is odd that you need to create the connection specially, but then you also need to do something special to activate the specialness.   But that is how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong `connection`. I had a HikariCP, and thought I could just take one of the connections from it.

But what you need to do, is to create a specific 'replication' connection. Something like:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    PGProperty.USER.set(props, "user");
    PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(props, "pass");
    PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(props, "9.4");
    PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(props, "database");
    PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(props, "simple");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the START_REPLICATION command is not being recognized by the PostgreSQL server.

One possible reason for this could be that the pgoutput extension, which provides logical decoding functionality, is not enabled in the database. You can try enabling it by running the following command in the PostgreSQL console:

CREATE EXTENSION pgoutput;
i hope this helps